# Update for: Help > How do I ask a good question

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, help-center, editor

This is the help topic I am referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

It states:

> If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

I think that this paragraph needs to be updated. The reason being that people are constantly talking about future proofing SO (including literally in the above quote) and have been actively removing online JavaScript editors (JsFiddle, JsBin, CodePen) in favor of the native Stack Snippet tool.

The wiki on the other hand makes reference to using such an online JavaScript editor. Note that this question is only about editors for JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

I think that the JsBin reference should be removed (Am fine with sqlfiddle or dotnetfiddle etc, as they actually require a compiler) and should be replaced with a recommendation to use the native Stack Snippet creator with a link to https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ or maybe something less outdated (perhaps [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)).

Comment: Related: [Add StackSnippets to the how-to-ask page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306199/1595451)

Comment: I haven't come across people actively removing these from posts yet. I guess I'm not as active as I thought in the suggested edits queue?

Comment: In many cases, the Snippet tool isn't ideal. For example, it doesn't allow for viewport resizing which makes it impossible to demonstrate responsive scenarios. I think the [warning message that's shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352305/restrict-fiddle-sencha-com-the-same-way-as-jsfiddle-net/352310) for external editors is already adequate.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I see it every once in a while but maybe OP ran into a bunch of edits from someone On A Mission who did a bunch at once.

Comment: I don't know that JsBin needs to be removed but a note that HTML/CSS/JavaScript questions can use Stack Snippets should also be there.

Comment: JSBin should definitely be removed because JSFiddle and CodePen are far superior, but the Stack Snippet feature is also plenty adequate.

Comment: @ZimSystem it allows for viewport resizing when you fullscreen the snippet (via dev tools)

Comment: @Zze - yes, but the are other inconveniences with the snippet tool. The external editors are simply better editors for many reasons. It's a good idea to update the guidance to recommend Stack Snippets, but I think it's wrong to be actively removing all the other editors.

Comment: Wait a minute, the snippet tool only works for 3 languages...